# WebView EvaluateJavaScriptAsync fails on ios

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

i have this xaml:

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <WebView x:Name="browser"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" />
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

and in the codefile:

```
    public BlankPage() {
            InitializeComponent();
            browser.Navigated += Browser_Navigated;
            browser.Source = "https://www.google.de";
        }
    private async void Browser_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e) {
            var res = await browser.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("alert('test');");
    }
```

On Android it works as aspected. The Messagebox appears. But on ios nothing happens. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: It works fine on my side , which device did you test ? Make sure that you can access the url in safari .

Comment: At iPhone 12 - iOS 14.4 Simulator.

Comment: Could you share your sample so that I can test it on my side directly .

Comment: Hi, now it works. I restartet VS and deleted bin/obj folder. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that "EvaluateJavaScriptAsync fails on ios" really? Maybe check if "Navigated event fails on ios", wouldn't be surprised at all..